# Reuse of elements in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, web

I have 2 master pages. I want header and footer to be the same. Which mean that if i change something in header of one master page the other master page should also adopt the change.

Comment: nested master pages.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx

Comment: Make the header an .ascx control?

Comment: Checkout this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that an embed it in both MasterPages.

Comment: How do i reuse user control ? Like if i have placed the header in content placeholder. How can I call it to other master pages.

Comment: Remove the header and place it in the user control, then you can add the user control anywhere in the masterpage.